# Difference NDVI not clipping to ROI

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

This code works fine. The only problem is that the result image is not clipped according to geometry. How can I solve this issue?

```
// Load the region of interest


// Define a time range
var startDate = ee.Date('2023-03-08');
var endDate = ee.Date('2023-03-15');

// Load the Sentinel-2 Harmonized dataset, filter by the time range and region of interest, and mask clouds
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .map(function(image) {
    var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
    var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
    var qa = image.select('QA60');
    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
    return image.updateMask(mask);
  });

// Define a function to calculate NDVI from an image
function calcNdvi(image) {
  return image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).toFloat().rename('ndvi')
    .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

// Map the NDVI function over the collection
var ndvi = collection.map(calcNdvi);

// Get the minimum and maximum NDVI values for each pixel
var ndviMin = ndvi.min();
var ndviMax = ndvi.max();

// Calculate the difference NDVI
var diffNdvi = ndviMax.subtract(ndviMin).toFloat().rename('diff_ndvi')
  .copyProperties(ndviMax, ["system:time_start"]);
print(diffNdvi);
// Display the difference NDVI image
Map.centerObject(geometry);

// Export the difference NDVI as a GeoTIFF
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: diffNdvi,
  description: 'difference_ndvi',
  folder: 'GEE Outputs',
  scale: 10,
  region: geometry
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filterBounds` doesn't clip images. You need the `clip` method. You may  also need to explicit cast to `ee.Image`.

```
diffNdvi = ee.Image(diffNdvi).clip(geometry);

Map.addLayer(diffNdvi);
```

Comment: You might want to wait with clipping until the last step in your processing too. See https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#if-you-dont-need-to-clip,-dont-use-clip